# Dungeon World starters for young girls?

Tags: published-adventures, dungeon-world

Does anyone know of any Dungeon World 'starters' aimed at younger players or girls in particular?

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand why this is a "shopping" question? I've chosen Dungeon World, and I'm not asking for comparisons with any other games or anything. I'm after ideas to use with my daughters in Dungeon World, and I think answers to that would also help a lot of other people trying to do the same thing as I am. Could someone let me know what edits I should make for this question to be clear and more acceptable? (I can't seem to see how to message other users for advice on editing. This is my first question, and to be honest I'd like to have a good first experience of this site.)

Comment: Welcome! Please take the [tour] when you get a chance; you might also find the [chat] room useful. This question as written isn't "shopping" so much as it is "recommendation request". The thing it seems to be thin on is criteria. We like questions with clear goals so we can avoid ambiguity and upvote the clearly best answer. If one answer points to a "unicorns as mounts" section and another the "clothing and jewelry" expansion, which is more correct? The up side is asking questions is free and unlimited. Try picking one thing to focus on, then defining acceptance criteria for it. Happy gaming!

Comment: Thanks for your help, Joel. I'm trying to get it... Would a better version of the question be "Does anyone know of a Dungeon World 'starter' aimed at younger players or girls in particular?" That has a clear enough goal I guess?

Comment: Sorry, I’m not sure there’s a way to change the question as it stands - we tried to allow remmendation questions on the site for a long time but they were the source of intractable quality problems so we had to ban them.  You could try asking about your actual problem, which could be answered with techniques or supplements - ‘i’m Trying to run DW for young girls’ - but of course you’d need to explain what the issue is you are having exactly.  How to run it with a more cartoony tone?  I played D&D at a young age so am not really sure what you really need here.

Comment: Yes, I'm trying to run DW for young girls (as a new and inexperienced GM), and I'm simply trying to get some concrete ideas (in the form of 'starters' or whatever else) to add to my own imaginative efforts. So it does actually sound like a reasonable question to me (and the most helpful answer can still be voted up). But perhaps I'm in the wrong place - I read somewhere that there was a good DW following out there and lots of fan material around, so perhaps someone could direct me to a site that doesn't think this question is strange or unreasonable? Are there even DW specific sites around?

Comment: We certainly can direct you to another site. (The strangeness isn’t your question, it’s this site: it only handles question that can have “best” answers.) For questions looking for ideas — which means they’re all equally valid, and valuable in volume rather than correctness — a normal discussion site is in order. We have put together [a list of such sites](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5449/321). Take a look through that list and its descriptions to see which one(s) appeals to your needs. Cheers!

Comment: Thanks for the list, I'll have a look through it. Though I still disagree that this question couldn't have a best answer. The best answer would simply be the one that led me to the most of the requested material. Nothing hard about that I don't think.